# Using PNP JS with SPFX 1.1

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-server, pnpjs

I am using SPFX 1.1 (because our SharePoint Environment is 2016) and tried to integrate PnP (Version 1.3.3).

I followed the instructions from here to switch to typescript 2.4.2 instead of 2.2.2
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/documentation/SPFx-On-Premesis-2016/

But every time I run **npm install**, the typescript version switches back to 2.2.2

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you replace all occurrences of typescript before running `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, every reference to the version 2.2.2